# LinqPad Error: Unable to find the .Net Framework Data Provider

Tags: linqpad

I am new to LinqPad.

I downloaded a .sdf file from the internet (i know what it is)  I wanted to view its tables.  So I googled "how to read .sdf files" and came across Linqpad, which I installed.

When I browse to my .sdf file from LinqPad and try to open it as a connection, I get the message "Unable to find the requested .Net framework data provider, it may not be installed"

Does this mean i need to install SQL CE before using LinqPad?  I assumed LinqPad was the program to view tables, run queries, etc and that I did not need the original db program.

Please advise on what the error refers to and best way to resolve.  thanks

Answer (score 13):

To answer your question, yes you do have to install it. I just ran across this problem while trying to connect to a Sql CE 3.5 DB in LinqPad. You have to have the proper version installed first. I only had 4.0 installed and was trying to connect to a 3.5 DB. So had to use the SSCERuntime msi found [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5783) to install the items shown below:

[image]

Just go to that link and download it somewhere and then run the msi(s).
Note the following:

> It is mandatory to install both the 32-bit and the 64-bit version of 
>   SQL Server Compact MSI files on a 64-bit Computer. Installing only the
>   32-bit version of the SQL Server  Compact 3.5 SP2 MSI file on a 64-bit
>   computer will lead to failure of the existing SQL Server Compact 3.5 
>   applications on the Computer.

So just follow the instructions shown in the "Install.txt" that is downloaded with the msi's.

After installing them I had to close and reopen LinqPad and then the connection worked.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add a variant on Kasper's solution. For the case of connecting to SQL CE 4, I appeared to already have the SQL CE4 runtimes installed yet I still got the same error.

Trying to install the latest SQL CE 4 [from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=17876) reported that a newer version was already installed and aborted the install.
Uninstalling the "newer version" and then installing the latest download fixed the problem for me.

I'm not sure how I got that original version, that's "newer" than the latest from Microsoft. Possibly from an older Visual Studio install.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to make a connection to your database. You can do that by clicking "Add Connection", "Default Linq to Sql connection" and then marking your version of SQL CE on top and providing the information.

LinqPad is not just viewing tables, run queries etc. It is much more than that.